# Por que depois de retirar o voto de fechamento não posso votar novamente?

Tags: debate, fechamento

Um exemplo:

Um usuário novo posta uma pergunta em inglês. Então eu voto para fechar por não estar em português. Mais tarde o usuário traduz a pergunta, então vou lá e retiro meu voto de fechamento. Porém, mesmo depois de traduzir, a pergunta ainda não está de acordo, por exemplo, amplo demais. A partir desse momento não posso votar novamente, desta vez, por ser amplo demais, pois o sistema supõe que já dei um voto na pergunta.

É certo isso? Por que não posso votar novamente se a pergunta continua fora do escopo do site?

Comment: Boa pergunta +1

Comment: @Math - Ótima edição, até pra mim ficou mais claro, hehe. ;)

Comment: Relevante: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254778/why-cant-we-vote-to-close-a-question-after-the-original-vote-was-retracted se alguém traduzir terá meu +1.

Comment: @Renan - De acordo com uma das respostas: _"You get one close vote on a question to reduce the possibility of open/close wars. If the question is to be closed again, it must be close by a different group of people than the ones who originally closed it."_ Basicamente ele disse: _"Você tem apenas 1 voto por pergunta para reduzir uma guerra abre/fecha. Se a questão merece ser fechada novamente, deve ser feito por um outro grupo de pessoas"_.

Comment: Eu falo inglês :p eu quis dizer traduzir como uma resposta, para que tenhamos uma resposta oficial para a pergunta aqui. Sinta-se a vontade, já tens meu +1 na pergunta, terá na resposta também.

Comment: Será que é uma resposta oficial? Bom, foi dada por um diamante(moderador)...

Comment: [Duplicata?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1962/troca-de-motivo-para-fechamento)

Comment: @Papa Como lá não tinha resposta, fechei aquela como dup desta.

Comment: @bfavaretto, sem problema.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De acordo com a resposta no SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254778/4178863

Tradução livre:

> Você tem apenas um voto por questão para reduzir a possibilidade de
>   guerras do tipo abre/fecha. Se uma pergunta deve ser fechada
>   novamente, deve ser fechada por um grupo diferente de pessoas das que
>   originalmente fecharam.
>
> Nenhum motivo de fechamento fecha a pergunta definitivamente. Todos os
>   fechamentos estão sujeitos a reabertura se for obtido o número
>   necessário de votos.
>
> O mesmo se aplica para duplicatas; você só tem uma mordida na maçã. Se
>   você errar, alguém tem que fechar na duplicata correta.